# Prove that the only solution to $n | (3^{n-1})^2 + 3^{n-1} + 1$ is $n = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In general, I'm having trouble reasoning about the order of 3 mod n, and divisors of n-1.

So far, I have that $\mathrm{ord}_n(3) :=m$, $m \not | \,\,\,n-1$ (or else we get $1+1+1 \equiv 0$)

I have $n \ne p$ for $p$ prime, and $n \ne qk$ for $k > q$ and $q = 2,3,5$.

I have that since $3^{n-1} \not \equiv 1$ mod $n$, $(3^{n-1})^3 \equiv 1$ mod $n$ iff $ (3^{n-1})^2 + 3^{n-1} + 1 \equiv 0$ mod $n$. So $m | 3n-3$.

So I'm not sure how to reason about the order of 3, or how exactly to drop down to congruence mod prime or prime power divisors of $n$. I feel that if I were able to do that, the question would fall apart in my hands to reveal the answer.

Edit: I have that if $m = 3^{\beta}a$ where $(a,3) =1$, and $n-1 = 3^\alpha b$, then $\beta > \alpha$ and $a|b\,$ (we can have that $\alpha = 0$). So in particular, $3|m$, and $(m,n-1) = a$.

Comment: What is it that you want to determine, the order of $3$ modulo an integer?

Comment: Knowing how the order of 3 mod n interacts with n-1 and perhaps p-1 where p|n.

Comment: And in general, if $p|n$, how does $p-1$ interact with $n-1$? eg. when do we get that $p-1 | n-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that, for some nonnegative integer $k$, $3^k\mid n-1$ and $3^{k+1}\nmid n-1$, for $n-1$ a positive integer.
Consider a prime $p\mid n$ (as $n\ge 1$). It is clear that $p\neq 3$. Otherwise, consider $m=\mathrm{ord}_p(3)$. Analagous to your proof earlier, one can show that
$$
m\mid 3(n-1)
$$
but
$$
m\nmid (n-1)
$$
Implying $3^{k+1}\mid m$. Now since $m\mid p-1$ (by Fermat's Little Theorem) we get that $3^{k+1}\mid p-1$ for all $p\mid n$. But this implies $3^{k+1}\mid n-1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why exactly do we have that $m|p-1$? I know that we have $3^m \equiv 3^{p-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $p$), but is $m$ still the order of 3 when you drop down to mod $p$? And how did you get the implication that $3^{k-1}|n-1$?

Comment: Never mind about the second question about $3^{k-1}\mid n-1$, but I'm still not sure about the first one.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo at first; the $m$ in my solution is different than the $m$ you described. I define $m=\mathrm{ord}_p(3)$ for some fixed $p$. We can prove that $m\mid 3(n-1)$, etc. because $p\mid (3^{n-1})^2+3^{n-1}+1$, and because $m$ is the order $\mod p$, we know that $m\mid p-1$.